# Page View Counts

Tags: visualforce

1. If your page is calling a **component** that serves as sidebar in your page, does it counts as page view?
2. I placed some images in Documents Object and not in Static Resource because there would be time that the images must be updated and we want to avoid doing the updates via codes so that non-developers could update it themselves. Question is, does images in Documents object also counts as page view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information. Are you referring to a Site page? What limitation are you concerned about?

Comment: thank you for the fast response. I'm talking about this: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US#SitesPageViewsWhatCounts

Comment: What does the component do...?

Comment: The component is a sidebar for a page. Other pages are using the same sidebar so it is placed in the components then the page will only call one component. Btw, I have confirmed that images placed in Documents Object are not counted as page views. Please follow the link below for more details, and jump to "What Counts as a Page View?" section.

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US#SitesPageViewsWhatCounts

So, the only question left is the question #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the limitations area, anything that invokes a Visualforce page will count as a page view. From my experimentation, it appears that Documents are not subject to bandwidth or page view limits, although it is hard to confirm, because I don't have a Site configured that has a page view limit (DE doesn't have normal limit for page views).

Components within a Visualforce page don't normally incur extra page views, unless they invoke code that causes a page to load or call a Visualforce remoting method. Similarly, pages that are included within pages don't accumulate extra views either, but there is a limit on maximum CPU time that will be affected by this.

Static resources should be used when possible because of the caching benefits and CDN benefits (faster loading, better caching, etc). Administrators can change static resources as easily as a document-- they just go to a different area to perform the swap.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the quick response. Paragraph two confirmed it! Also extra info is so appreciated. Again, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @sfdcfox Is possible to store customer information(unauthenticated ) in salesforce whenever someone visit the site. i mean customer city/country and Latitude and Longitude data in salesforce.

Comment: @Sekhar Getting latitude/longitude data from their computer would require permission from the visitor. You could get a general location by checking their IP address, but it's not 100% accurate.