# Can someone please explain page views on force.com

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, limits

Can someone please breakdown for me what "Warning: Page Views Are at 90% of Your Limit" means.

It seems our force.com (community) are causing this us to reach our limit of 500,000 a month.

I'm not understanding how we are getting close to 500,000 page views, its great if we are, but really? We are using OrchestraCMS thats hosted on force.com

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce provides an appexchange package to report on your page view usage and other force.com sites statistics - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SUEwEAO

Orchestra uses Force.com sites and Visualforce to display content to site visitors, so the more people that are visiting and using your site, the more page views you'll utilise - hopefully that's a good thing for your business :-)

If you're using a Public Knowledge Base, that may also be contributing.

You can license extra pages from Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the limitations area, anything that invokes a Visualforce page will count as a page view. From my experimentation, it appears that Documents are not subject to bandwidth or page view limits, although it is hard to confirm, because I don't have a Site configured that has a page view limit (DE doesn't have normal limit for page views).

Components within a Visualforce page don't normally incur extra page views, unless they invoke code that causes a page to load or call a Visualforce remoting method. Similarly, pages that are included within pages don't accumulate extra views either, but there is a limit on maximum CPU time that will be affected by this.

Static resources should be used when possible because of the caching benefits and CDN benefits (faster loading, better caching, etc). Administrators can change static resources as easily as a document-- they just go to a different area to perform the swap.

Source : - [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21948/page-view-counts)